# verify recaptcha html code

Tags: html, recaptcha

From the google site, I cam across a code that lets me display the recaptcha box. Although I must admit I have only started html today and hence, have no basics at all. The site does not have a verify code in html although it does in jsp and I dont know how to link it all since data from the html went to the servlet.

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify
specifis a list of parameters to be 'posted'

I am using Tomcat 7 and no Spring.

My doubts:

1. Can I have multiple forms in an html file
2. How do i send parameters from the precious form to the second form?
3. How do I link a jsp file that will verify it to be run through the java class invoked by the html file
4. How do I get the user (accessing my app through a local server) remote IP address?

Comment: That's five questions in one. Better to ask all these separately. One question per question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got sorted out. Since I did not understand the problem in that, I proceeded to simple captcha itself. I must admit I feel like a fool saying I din't know html/jsp. The second day it was all so clear. I must have been positively psyched. Unwilling to see the not working code again, I started fresh.

Answers :

1. I can have multiple forms in a html
2. as set and get parameter as a session and request functions respectively.
3. through a form itself or response.sendredirect("")
4. Remote address class and methods.